# Spring Integration : jms to ftp

Tags: ftp, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I'm brand new to Spring Integration, and while trying to discover all the functionality it provides, find myself a bit lost with some of its syntax.

Let me explain what do i need, and how do i think it's the way to implement it.

I have an external process that send messages to an ActiveMQ Queue ( standard jms ), and i do need a product that

- Receive the messages from the queue
- Transform and combine the messages ( to send 1 file with 100 message instead of 100 files with 1 message )
- Deliver the results to a ftp server

So, i do believe that to accomplish this, i need :

1. jms-inbound-channel
2. Service aggregator ( i need to combine 100 messages into one )
3. Ftp outboud channel

Am i missing something ?

Comment: hey josete: could you please share sample code for JMS-FTP integration?

Answer (score 1):

For #2 you can use a `<file:outbound-channel-adapter/>` to APPEND to the file and then use some other criteria to determine when to send that file to the `<ftp:outbound-channel-adapter/>`.

You also might find it better to use a `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter/>` rather than polling the inbound adapter.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direccion, as I've found that the message-driven-channel is the one i need, but i can't find yet why should i use a file:outbound channel instead of a service aggregator .. as it allows me to know when to send the file ( release-strategy )

Comment: I was just suggesting an alternative - it might need less code, but your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hello gary: Could you plz look into this and suggest some help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841514/how-to-send-xml-jms-message-to-ftp-in-spring-integration