# How to send XML JMS message to FTP in Spring integration

Tags: java, xml, ftp, jms, spring-integration

I'm trying to send `XML` message to `FTP` in `Spring Integration` using `active MQ`. Text message is working fine at Receiver `Queue` and I can print message in console but how can I send this message to `FTP` outbound adapter which need to store in a `XML` `file` in local directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not at all clear; XML **is** text. The FTP adapter can handle a String payload so you can simply receive the XML from JMS in a message and send it to the FTP adapter directly; there is no need to write to a file first.

Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

Comment: Gary: I'm very new in SI. I have a JMS message from Active MQ which I can receive and see in my eclipse console. Now how can I send it to FTP adapter. ( I Can share my personnel mail id if you want) please help.